# Complete QGIS clean up

Tags: qgis, installation

Can anybody tell how to completely clean up your desktop computer from QGIS files ( Windows Registry, user folders and program folders)?

It's for QGIS version 2.4 and 2.10.

'Ok' and 'cancel' buttons are missing from dialog boxes in QGIS project, and despite uninstalling QGIS the same error appear when installing new version, even 2.8.5 (Long term release).

Therefore a complete clean up of QGIS is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try Revo uninstaller with deep scan for leftover files and registry entries option after uninstall.  http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html